# My move speed is automatically changing for no reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I set the move speed of my player to 1, but when I start the game and move it goes from 1 to 0.07 for some reason, and I don't know why.
Code:
`

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed = 1f;
        public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;
        public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;

        Vector2 movementInput;
        Rigidbody2D rb;
        List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
           if(movementInput != Vector2.zero)
           {
                int count = rb.Cast(
                    movementInput,
                    movementFilter,
                    castCollisions,
                    moveSpeed = Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset);

                if(count == 0)
                {
                     rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movementInput * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                }
           }
         }

        void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
        {
            movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
        }
    }
```

`

I couldn't figure out anything about the problem, but as you can probably tell, the move speed isn't meant to change, it's just meant to stay at 1. Any help appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

This

```
moveSpeed = Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset
```

is an assignment and is modifying your `moveSpeed`.

Looks to me like it should rather have been

```
moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset
```